# ActiveRecord query that groups by ID and sums rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

My Postgresql DB has this structure:

```
TABLE Orders
id (string)
userId (string)
prodId (string)
value (integer)
```

This is an example of data:

```
id      userId      prodId    value
1       a@a.aaa     prod1     5
2       b@b.bbb     prod1     -1
3       a@a.aaa     prod1     -4
4       a@a.aaa     prod2     9
```

I want to do a query from ActiveRecord that sums all the values for a specific `userId`, so the query for (a@a.aaa) would return a LIST like this:

```
prod1    1
prod2    9
```

My first approach is this one, but it doesn't work:

```
orderList = Orders.select("SUM(orders.amount) AS num_prods").where((:userId => HERE_USER_ID).group(:prodId)
```

**EDIT:** rephrased thanks to feedback

Comment: 1. You probably want `Order` instead of `Orders`. 2. Is your user column called `userId` or `username`?  You have indicated different values in your example data and your ActiveRecord query.  3.  You have an extra `(` on your `where` condition.  4. When you say "doesn't work", what happens?

Comment: Thanks, actually I expressed myself incorrectly. Please, find new query

Comment: Is your model called `Order` or `Orders`?  Is the first line in it `class Order < ActiveRecord::Base`?

Comment: The model is called Orders and the database table is called orders. I know that I should change that to singular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Order.where(userId: id).group(:prodId).sum(:value) # replace `:id` with your value
```

This should give you a hash, like so

```
{1=>10, 2=>20, 5=>20}
```

the keys `1,2,5` represent the product id, and the values `10,20,20` represent the sum values.